# What should be the value for the resistor for this circuit?

Tags: led, transistors, resistors

Sorry for this silly question but I am not from an electronics background. I am trying to build a very basic circuit with npn transistor to detect a certain water level. I am assuming the resistance of water to be 200k ohm thats why I have connected a 200k ohm resistor between base of transistor and positive terminal of battery. The transistor will be acting like a switch to allow a bigger current to light up the led. I will be using a 15 v power adapter (it says its a 15V ~ 533mA source) and I can't use another and a 3V led. Transistor is a NPN BR N5551 bg49.

My question is what should be the value of resistor X so that I don't burn out the LED.

[image]

Comment: This schematic hurts my brain

Comment: "I am assuming the resistance of water to be 200k ohm". Just stop right there. If you want to detect a water level get a float switch or other purpose built sensor and go from there.

Comment: Sorry but I told you I am not from an electronics background. Please help me out I need to build it somehow.

Comment: @ACD Stand on your head and cross your eyes. You can understand it then - and understand how bad a circuit it is ;)

Comment: I came here with a hope that someone will help. I know I am bad with electronic circuits and admit that the circuit drawn above sucks in schematics but please can anyone ... anyone, help me with that ?

Comment: Circuit won't work, but for the LED R you want ~5-10mA through the LED, so something around a 2 k ohm resistor would be fine.  (I think it has some small chance of working if you flip the transistor around.. emitter to ground.

Answer (score 3):

First off, your transistor is backwards. Emitter should connect to ground.

Switching to an N-channel MOSFET instead of a BJT would make it simpler, since it is a voltage driven device, not current,

You will need to bias the transistor so it can switch on when the voltage across the water sensor rises past a certain point.  Using a simple resistive divider with the right values should do the trick.  Something like:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fO1UP0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Assuming ~200KΩ resistance for the water probe, that resistance along with R2 will form a voltage divider with the voltage either 0V when the water tank is empty, or ~12V when it has water (you can reduce R2 to reduce the sensitivity).  That then switches on Q1 into saturation mode, where it allows current to flow, thus illuminating D1.  Note the gate threshold voltage should be no more than half the gate's on voltage, so around 5V would be fine - or even lower.

The value for R1 is calculated assuming a 2.2V forward voltage (Vf) and 20mA current (If) for D1, and is:

\$R = \frac{V_{IN} - V_F}{I_F} = 640Ω\$

To allow the power supply to vary (especially if it's not a regulated one) a higher resistor should be selected - I have gone for 1KΩ. There would be little or no visible difference in the light. You could even go higher, say 2.2KΩ, and it'll still be plenty bright enough, and use less current.

Comment: Hey thanks for answering. I have a doubt here. Correct me if I am wrong. Isn't it the way that if we give a low voltage to the base the current flows from collector to emitter ? What I was trying is that I simulated lower voltage to base by connecting a 200k ohm resistor so that remaining voltage flows from collector to emitter. I know I am really bad with circuits :(

Comment: Yes, but a resistor by itself doesn't regulate the voltage, it regulates the current, and 200KΩ directly across 15V would only give you 75µA.

Comment: Ya I was getting very low current across the LED to be precise 75µA (as you said) while simulating this circuit that's why LED was not glowing. What should be done in order to rectify it ? Are you telling me that water will behave differently than the resistor ?

Comment: When your probes are in water they will act like a resistor, yes. But, when they're not in water, they are an open circuit - and one of the probes (the one connected to the base) will act like an antenna. It's perfectly possible that it will cause the LED to light when you don't want it to - it's what we call a "floating input" as the value on it isn't known. By adding the 1MΩ resistor you are forcing a known "off" value when the probe is out of water, and then you will either need 2 transistors (See the other answer) or a MOSFET to react to V instead of I.

Answer (score 2):

The circuit you show has the transistor inverted which is .. bad. BJTs still work (sort-of) when inverted but the gain will be very low (probably less than 20), and the breakdown voltage will be less than 10V most likely.

This should more-or-less work, if the water is actually 200K. R1 represents the water, R2 and R3 are real resistors. I still don't recommend it, for reasons given below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEpBP6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that if the water is present continuously, electrolysis will eat away the electrodes over time (kind of reverse electroplating).

With just a single transistor, the gain won't be high enough to get full brightness
from the LED and it will pass more current through the electrodes (meaning it will eat them away much faster).

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I know that electodes will corrode. What if use stainless stell electrodes ? Can you please explain what biasing does in breaf ?

Comment: Stainless steel electrodes will corrode too. R2 just pulls the base voltage down so the LED will turn off when the conductivity is not present. The water pulls up the voltage so that the LED begins to turn on when the resistance is a few megohms and will be fully on when the resistance is a couple hundred K ohms. This circuit allows the brightness of the LED to indicate the amount of conductivity- it is not intended to switch sharply.